# tableView property declaration or linkages

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, properties, tableview

I have a View (SearchView) with a SearchDisplayController and a TableView

in .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

I linked this in .xib file to the TableView: >
[image: see linkages here]

Then in cellforrow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


if(listGoal){
    
    Goal *goalz = nil;
    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        goalz = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = goalz.goalNaam;
    }
    else
    {
        
        goalz = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = goalz.goalNaam;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = goalz.goalBeschrijving;
    }
}
```

I test if I need the filteredListContent or the original array, arr. (Because I'm using a SearchDisplayController)
Which is working.

In another method,

```
 if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

is not working anymore, so I tried using

```
self.tableView
```

but this isn't working either and

```
  (UITableView *)tableView
```

isn't working either.
I know something is wrong with my property declaration or linkages, but what is wrong ?

Comment: I think searchTableView is available only when it is being displayed on screen.
In which method does it not work for you?

Comment: in a custom method, in the same class. How can I call the tableview the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can access search view in your custom method would be keep a strong reference to your search view when you get it. But I am NOT sure whether it would be valid across multiple searches.

May be you can just have a BOOL variable set and use that in your custom method. I think you would not be able to access search view in your custom method otherwise.

Comment: I changed the "tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView" with a BOOLEAN "filtered", now it works. But tableview should be accessible, isn't it..

Comment: Yes, tableView should be accessible in your custom method, if its a member variable and you have a valid reference to it available.